# Can 3Ω speakers match 4~16Ω amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, speakers, impedance-matching, power-amplifier

I have a set of Samsung home theatre system. The Samsung DVD player is no longer working. I would like to get a new amplifier and reuse the 5 existing Samsung speakers.

But the existing speakers are all labelled 3Ω and the new amplifier is labelled 4-16Ω (1200W).

It seems that the speakers (3Ω) has lower impedance than the amplifier (4-16Ω). I worry the amplifier will be toast. But two different online shops confidently  told me they can be paired.

I have watched many YouTube tutorials about amplifier-speaker matching but still in the mist.

Can someone please give me a little advice? I really appreciate. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

BELOW: The new amplifier rear label. It’s 1200W.
[image]

BELOW: Specs of new amplifier. 
[image]

Comment: It specifically says 4-16 ohms required for the FL/FR, so it could work but the amp might not like it and go to protect mode. But the other speakers require 8-16 ohms, why even try connecting speakers with incorrect rating to it? You read the manual and believe it, and the manual says no, you can't connect.

Comment: 3 is 33% lower than 4 so I wouldn't recommend it. Though with really long speaker cables you might just get away with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

impedance matches aren't important with trasnsistor amplifiers. it will work so long as you don't turn the sound up too loud.

if the amplitude is too high currents exceeding those it was designed to produce will flow which could damage it and the speakers too.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. Really helpful.